# How to set share image width via FB.ui

Tags: facebook, image, user-interface, size

I am using FB.ui() to share a page and on mobile the og image is cropped to a square, instead of being desiplayed entirely.
The natural size of my og image 1200x622. How can I specify its dimensions using FB.ui method?

Here is the code I am using:

```
FB.ui({
method: 'share',
action_type: 'og.shares',
href: 'http://example.com/',
title: 'My title',
picture: 'http://example.com/picture.jpg',
description: 'My description'
}, function(response){
console.log(response);
});
```

Thank you,
Andru

Answer (score 0):

You can´t change the share image in the Share Dialog, you need to use the Feed Dialog for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/

If you want to use the Share Dialog, make sure you follow the guidelines to get the best picture after sharing: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Also, you should include the size directly in your HTML code:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
```

Source: http://ogp.me/

If all those things don´t work for you, you can file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. I don't want to change the share image. All I want is to specify to Facebook to use the full size uncropped image (eg: http://example.com/picture.jpg).

Comment: I have previously created a custom story and I was able to fix this exact issue using this code:
'FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'ddpersonalitea:share',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
     'quiz': {
       'og:type': 'ddpersonalitea:quiz',
       'og:url': 'https://.../',
       'og:title': 'title',
       'og:description': 'description',
       'og:image': 'image.jpg',
       'og:image:width' : '1200',
       'og:image:height' : '630'
     }
    })
   }, function(response){    
   });'

Comment: that is exactly what i meant. facebook decides about the size, i will include a link to the specifications. you need to follow them for the picture.

Comment: I tried the same thing for a regular share and it didn't work. Here is the code I tried:

    'FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object : {
               'og:url': 'http://...',
               'og:title': 'title',
               'og:description': 'description',
               'og:image': 'image.jpg',
               'og:image:width': '1200',
               'og:image:height': '622'
            }
        })
  }, function(response){
   console.log(response);
  });'

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting:

 `FB.ui({
   method: 'share_open_graph',
   action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object : {
               'og:url': 'http://...',
               'og:title': 'title',
               'og:description': 'description',
               'og:image': 'image.jpg',
               'og:image:width': '1200',
               'og:image:height': '622'
            }
        })
  }, function(response){
   console.log(response);
  });`

Comment: open graph share is completely different. i assume you don´t want to share open graph actions/stories. i will include some info about the width/height og tags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I would like to clarify a bit more my issue.

Comment: The sharing on this particular page MUST be done via FB.ui(). The meta tags are not applicable to my situation, because the sharing headlin, content and image are dynamic, meaning that depending on some user interactivity they will vary. Therefore, my only choice is to somehow specify the "og:image:width" and "og:image:height" properties via js. Is there a way to adjust the sample code I sent so that it can pass these 2 variables to Facebook, so that the image will not be cropped in the share dialog?

Comment: here is the actual link to the page I am working on: http://pfpizzaquiz.com/
If you click on one pizza slice, you will get to a second screen where you can share the results. Note that on desktop, the sharing image is the correct one. Only on mobile the cropping occurs.

Comment: did you try the suggestion from my answer? the feed dialog? that´s how it usually works, although i would rather use the share dialog and make sure that there IS an url with open graph tags. that´s the proper way, after all "sharing" is about "sharing an url", and users should know what they can expect behind the url.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected on either desktop or mobile. 
On desktop is slightly crops the image on the right side (4-5% probably)
On mobile, it shows the entire image, however is more like a thumbnail floated to the left. And I wanted to see the entire image same width as the share dialogue.
As I mentioned, I was able to make this work with custom stories by passing the 'og:image:width': '1200', 'og:image:height': '622' as properties in the action_properties: JSON.stringify({...}). However, when I tried the same for share it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: in that case, there´s most likely nothing else you can do. you could file a bug though.

Comment: I did. Nobody answered that: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=972432319503473
That's unexpected poor support form FB.

Comment: that´s not a bug report, this is the correct platform: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/