# How to show full width image via FB.ui?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using FB.ui() to share a post. The size of my image 1200x600. Everything is working perfectly expect image dimension. It is showing in thumbnail, however my image dimension is 1200X600 so as per Facebook rule my post share image will should be show in full width if dimension is 1200X600.

Following is my html code:

```
<div class='col-md-12 text-center' style='padding:5px 45px'>
    <input type='hidden' value='".$eventName."' id='fb_title' />
    <input type='hidden' value='".$base_url."/images/".$fb_image."' id='fb_image'>
    <input type='hidden' value='".$fb_description."' id='fb_desc' />
    <input type='hidden' value='".$base_url."/events/".$eventUrl."' id='fb_link'>
    <button class='btn btn-primary font_family' id='shareBtn'><i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>&nbsp;Share on facebook</button>
</div>
```

Following is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#shareBtn').click(function(){
    var fb_title = $('#fb_title').val();
    var fb_image = $('#fb_image').val();
    var fb_desc = $('#fb_desc').val();
    var fb_link = $('#fb_link').val();

    FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: fb_title,
            link: fb_link,
            picture: fb_image,
            description: fb_desc
        });
});
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the category of your app?

Comment: I think you need to do this using the share api rather than the feed api? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35251533/368186

Comment: @CBroe category of my app is business.

Comment: Ok, because for apps in the Games category Facebook deliberately uses the small, square image format. I am not sure if this is maybe another limitation when posting “dynamic” data via the dialog; I would suggest you try if you get a different result when you just share a link that has the rest (title, description, image) set via Open Graph meta tags. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Comment: @JimJeffries i have tried same but same result is showing my image showing in thumbnail.

Comment: @CBroe i have shared a link that has the title, description and image and it is showing perfectly in FB post. Image is showing with full width.